# In the Political Compass test, what does "left libertarian" mean?

Tags: ideology, terminology, libertarianism

I took a political compass quiz and it categorized me as "left libertarian". What does this mean?

If it is a party, then I don't know anything about it, and I was wondering if anyone knew of it, and if they did, what are the major tenets of its overall party platform?

If it's not a party, then what does "Left Libertarian" mean?

Comment: You should get rid of the fluff and ask a specific question. This is a question and answer site, not a forum.

Comment: Also, do you mean Libertarian? Because there are already questions asking about it.

Comment: Please [edit] clarifications (such as your country) into your question, rather than leaving them buried in comments where no one will see them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because because it is basically asking us to choose who you should vote for in an upcoming election.

Comment: Left/Right don't have any real meaning. In the USA, the left is associated with the Democrat party. I am pretty sure you mean libertarian, not liberation (which is more associated with armies fighting occupying forces). Libertarians value liberty/freedom. The point of those political spectrum quizzes isn't to determine which party you would vote for, but to determine your own political leanings.

Comment: Without even a link to the specific quiz, it's impossilbe to answer this question.

Comment: Is it possibly this chart and you got Left-Libertarian? http://cdn.playbuzz.com/cdn/e9920e89-b1dd-4c21-8bc6-8c82fcbeb99a/7cdc96e6-b643-4d67-aa74-671b213569f0_560_420.jpg

Comment: In my honest opinion, those two dimensional charts are just as meaningless as the left/right scale they're supposed to replace.

Comment: I edited the question for clarity and English. I also nominated it to be reopened. We have other terminology questions out there, and this is relevant to politics as defined in the help center insofar as "left libertarians" have some consistent views on policies or political processes.

Comment: @indigochild The 'right' answer to this question would be a link-only to I presume politicalcompasstest.com/faq#what_does_it_mean? or something very much like it.

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt - A link-only answer is never the "right" one. It could probably just be a simple summary of that content, though.

Answer (score 2):

There are numerous online politics quizzes that will put you onto a graph that looks something like this

[image]

This chart is from politicalcompass.org, and you can visit that site for more information.

---

This is what I assume you're talking about.

**Left** and "**Libertarian**" are on different axes on the chart.

- **Left** is another word for "Liberal", and the "Liberal" party in the United States is the Democratic party.  Usually, the Left is in favor of changing society into something new.
- **Right** is another word for "Conservative", and the "Conservative" party in the United States is the Republican party.  Usually, the Right is in favor of keeping society as it is, or bringing it back to what it use to be.
- **Libertarian** means you value freedom, and reduced government control  there is a Libertarian party in the United States, but it isn't as large as the 2 major parties.
- **Authoritarian** is the opposite of Libertarian.  Authoritarians are in favor of a lot of government control.  I don't know what the Authoritarian party in the United States is, but I wouldn't be too surprised if one existed.

Comment: Libertarian is neither left and right. The reason is if the states is out, it doesn't matter whether the states is left or right. I think a left libertarian would tend to favor a bit of wealth redistribution. May be someone like George Hendry.

Comment: In Political Compass, "left" and "right" are about economics (so "left" is socialist and "right" is capitalist), while "libertarian" and "authoritarian" are only about personal freedom, not economic freedom (high economic freedom aka free market is "right" in this chart). So "left-libertarian" in Political Compass means more or less "socialist or social-democrat on economics and permissive on most moral issues" - imagine a hippie. American libertarians are "right-libertarian" on Political Compass.